# How to get Frequency Distribution Table using LaTEX in python code?

Tags: python, pandas, latex

```
for i in range(25):  
    str(i)+'-'+ str(i+1) - wind speed bins   
    for j in range(12):   
      fdh[i][j]=fd[i][j]/6.   
      print np.round(fdh[i][j],2) - frequency distribution values for 12 sectors
```

I want to get `frequency distribution table` with two columns Wind Speed and Wind Direction sectors(0 30 60 90 120 150 180 210 240 270 300 330). For each wind speed bin 12 values should be printed as a row. Below is my output in python.

```
0-1 m/s  3.83 6.0 6.33 3.83 4.0 3.5 4.33 2.5 2.67 4.5 8.5 6.33 

1-2 m/s  23.0 20.67 35.83 31.33 24.83 21.67 21.5 21.83 24.0 27.67 20.83 31.33 

2-3 m/s  39.67 37.5 68.17 66.0 54.0 35.0 41.83 54.33 54.5 49.5 49.0 50.17 

3-4 m/s  58.83 53.0 96.0 91.83 95.67 45.83 56.33 84.5 83.0 69.67 85.5 89.83 

4-5 m/s  60.0 69.67 82.83 109.83 125.83 58.67 50.33 147.67 136.33 80.17 92.33 86.67 

5-6 m/s  65.0 62.67 63.17 97.67 142.83 74.33 78.0 173.33 131.17 80.0 105.33 80.0 

6-7 m/s  64.17 56.83 45.0 79.33 137.83 80.0 84.83 204.17 131.33 87.67 92.17 67.5 

7-8 m/s  54.5 57.17 52.0 76.33 145.17 92.33 88.83 230.33 146.83 114.5 69.67 61.0 

8-9 m/s  52.83 42.0 40.0 83.5 130.83 71.67 98.0 246.83 170.0 152.5 46.83 56.83 

9-10 m/s  37.17 37.67 21.17 65.5 125.17 61.33 92.83 223.83 177.5 168.33 49.67 45.5 

10-11 m/s  28.67 26.17 12.83 60.0 100.83 48.17 77.33 204.0 193.33 144.5 51.67 46.5 

11-12 m/s  14.5 13.5 10.0 37.83 80.0 30.0 52.67 173.0 162.83 117.83 54.0 40.67 

12-13 m/s  8.5 8.17 6.0 25.33 42.5 18.17 33.0 144.5 149.67 99.83 34.0 30.33 

13-14 m/s  8.83 6.83 2.33 16.33 33.83 9.17 17.83 119.5 134.0 81.67 20.0 19.67 

14-15 m/s  10.67 4.0 2.67 11.67 18.33 5.33 10.5 91.83 112.5 66.0 13.0 17.5 

15-16 m/s  7.83 3.0 2.5 4.83 5.67 3.67 4.67 70.17 102.33 50.33 10.5 12.0 

16-17 m/s  5.33 0.5 2.17 1.0 1.67 0.83 2.33 50.0 76.83 47.17 12.33 5.67 

17-18 m/s  4.0 0.5 0.83 0.0 1.0 0.33 0.67 38.5 55.67 34.17 12.33 3.5 

18-19 m/s  1.83 0.83 1.5 0.0 0.17 0.0 0.33 23.67 44.0 37.0 6.33 3.67 

19-20 m/s  1.33 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.17 17.83 28.83 26.67 6.0 3.0 

20-21 m/s  1.0 0.33 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 11.17 22.17 26.0 2.83 1.17 

21-22 m/s  0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.33 8.0 11.83 17.5 2.17 0.33 

22-23 m/s  0.17 0.17 0.67 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 4.67 11.0 16.17 1.33 0.0 

23-24 m/s  0.0 0.17 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 4.67 5.67 12.0 0.33 0.0 

24-25 m/s  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.33 4.67 5.83 0.0 0.0
```

How to write in LaTEX code in python to get frequency table ? Here is my latex code in python for pdf report.

```
outfile.write('\\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}|}'+'\n')  
outfile.write('\\hline'+'\n')  
outfile.write('\\small\\textbf{\\color{black!50!black}Wind Speed(m/s)} & \\small\\textbf{\\color{black!50!black}Wind Direction(deg)}\\tabularnewline'+'\n')
outfile.write('\\hline'+'\n')  
for i in range(25):  
     for j in range(12):  
         outfile.write('\\small + str(i)+'-'+ str(i+1)+' & '+ '%.2f'%(np.round(fdh[i][j],2))+' \\tabularnewline'+'\n')
     outfile.write('\\hline'+'\n')  
outfile.write('\\end{tabular}'+'\n')
```

Below is the pdf frquency distribution table Iam getting in final report.

```
Wind Speed(m/s) Wind Direction(deg)  
0-1                   3.83  
0-1                   6.00  
0-1                   6.33  
0-1                   3.83  
0-1                   4.00  
0-1                   3.50  
0-1                   4.33  
0-1                   2.50  
0-1                   2.67  
0-1                   4.50  
0-1                   8.50  
0-1                   6.33  
1-2                   23.00    
1-2                   20.67  
and so on
```

Please help me..!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to get LaTeX to simply give you back the original table?  I'm assuming that in this answer.

You should first learn about how `r'string'` works.  If you put an `r` right before a string, it is interpreted as a raw string.  You won't need to escape the backslashes.

```
outfile.write(r'\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}|}'+'\n')  
outfile.write(r'\hline'+'\n')  
outfile.write(r'\small\textbf{\color{black!50!black}Wind Speed(m/s)} & \small\textbf{\color{black!50!black}Wind Direction(deg)}\tabularnewline'+'\n')
outfile.write(r'\hline'+'\n')  
for i in range(25):  
     outfile.write(r'\small '+str(i)+ '-' + str(i+1) + ' & ')
     for j in range(12):  
         outfile.write('%.2f'%(np.round(fdh[i][j],2))+ ' & ')
     outfile.write(r'\hline'+r'\n')  
outfile.write(r'\end{tabular}'+r'\n')
```

If I correctly understand your problem and what you want to see, the issue was that you had some things you wanted done only once per line and some that you wanted done multiple times per line, but they were ALL appearing in the same nested for loop.